# OpenMP critical section vs locks

Tags: openmp

What is the difference between **OpenMP** locks and critical section? Are they just alternatives for each other?
For example if I am writing to a same file using multiple files, should I use the locking or just the critical section before writing into the file?

Comment: What are you writing to the file? Are you writing from each thread? Do you use tasks or parallel loops? Do you write from all threads? Do you have some code? Which language do you have in mind? (OpenMP supports Fortran, C and C++) Your question is very broad and hard to answer, you should narrow it.

Comment: OK i will just try a simple operation.I have taken a char buffer in c++ and while one thread is writing to this buffer i just want the other threads should not try to read or write into this buffer.Only  one thread at a time should have the access to the buffer.It may read or write into that buffer..So shall I include writing in buffer under critical section or rather use locks

Comment: It really depends on the overall design of your code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018965/openmp-lock-vs-critical/17019907 and possibly others here on SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Critical sections will most commonly use a lock internally, e.g.:

- libgomp: [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/critical.c)
- libiomp:

> If the optional (name) is omitted, it locks an unnamed global mutex. 
>   
>   The OpenMP specification guarantees the following behaviour:

>

> The critical construct restricts execution of the associated
>   structured  block to a single thread at a time

A critical section therefore serves the same purpose as acquiring a lock. The difference is that the low-level details are handled for you.

I would advise you to use `critical` whenever possible due to the simplicity. If you have separate blocks that need to be critical but don't interfere with each other give them names, and only if you need some behaviour that cannot be accommodated by the annotations, use explicit locking.

Comment: Your source is one particular run-time library. Do you have any evidence to make this claim universal? And more importantly,  are those locks in the referenced source file really OpenMP locks or something lower level?

Comment: From the OpenMP specification: `The critical construct restricts execution of the associated structured block to a 
single thread at a time.` This clearly implies some form of mutex semantics. I showed that in (arguably) the most popular opensource implementation it simply uses locks internally. The key point (use one or the other) remains valid.

Comment: Editted to incorporate some of my findings.