# How to solve race condition on OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, race-condition

```
bool clusterExists(std::string& infoSet) {
    bool exists {false};
#pragma omp critical
    exists = mInfoMap.find(infoSet) != mInfoMap.end();

    return exists;
}

InfoSet* get(std::string& infoSet, const int& numActs, Env::History& actions) {
    if (numActs > 0 && mCreateNotExists && !clusterExists(infoSet)) {
#pragma omp critical
        {
            mInfoMap.insert({infoSet, new InfoSet {numActs}});

            for (auto& a : actions) {
                mInfoMap[infoSet]->insertActStr(Env::ActToStr(std::get<1>(a)), std::get<2>(a));
            }
        }
    }

    return mInfoMap[infoSet];
}
```

I believe that the problem is in "insert".
The problem is it because a map is a "STL container" and it needs a lock?

Comment: One option, don't use open mp and use `std::thread`/`std::async`/`std::mutex`/`std::scoped_lock` etc.? In the end you always have to write code to avoid race conditions. Also make sure all the calls you make are threadsafe e.g is `Env::ActToStr` threadsafe? (if it uses a static buffer you will have issues)

Comment: Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given enough code so I don't know what the OMP parallel part looks like, but I'm guessing that your `critical`, once you get it to work, will completely negate any parallel performance.

One way to make your code very fast is to give each thread its own version of the map, do completely independent/parallel insertions, and reconcile the local maps in the end. The most elegant way to do that is that define `operator+` on your map, and make the parallel section a `reduction(+:mymap)`.

That will run with almost perfect speedup, but beware that this will multiply memory demand by the number of threads. If you map is very big -- and so insert collisions are unlikely -- use locks instead of a critical section. With a critical section, only one thread can do an update, no matter where in your data structure. If you put locks on elements or sets of elements of the database, multiple updates can happen simultaneously, as long as they don't access the same section.

Comment: I think you should explain how/why a lock would be preferable to a (named) critical section. Else this looks to be in conflict with e.g. [OpenMP critical section vs locks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588159/10107454)

Comment: Now I will try to give more code, but isn't easy because the app is very big. Btw, yes the map is very big

Comment: @paleonix I disagree with that answer. I've added my reasoning on when what is appropriate.

Comment: With multiple locks I understand your reasoning. Although it depends a lot on the application/data if this is a reasonable approach. +1